# Laravel 7 - How to remove trailing slash URLs from my application?

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, redirect

I have already tried changing the .htaccess file, tried several solutions to it, nothing works. Whenever I add a trailing slash to the URL it opens another page, which should not happen, adding a trailing slash to the URL should redirect it to the URL without a trailing slash. I tried the following solutions:

[Solution 1](https://www.danielmorell.com/guides/htaccess-seo/redirects/https-www-and-trailing-slash)

[Solution 2](https://webdevetc.com/programming-tricks/apache-htaccess/htaccess-rewrite-and-redirection-rules/remove-trailing-slash-redirect-to-remove-trailing-slash-in-htaccess)

What I want to achieve is **http://127.0.0.1:8080/login/** should be redirected to  **http://127.0.0.1:8080/login** for every URL in my application.

**public/.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

**routes/web.php**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

// Navigation Menu
Route::get('advisor', 'AdvisorController@index');
Route::get('investment', 'InvestmentController@index');
Route::get('investor', 'InvestorController@index');
Route::get('product', 'ProductController@index');
Route::get('rate', 'RateController@index');
//  Stop registration other functions
 Auth::routes([
    'register' => false, // Registration Routes...
    'reset' => false, // Password Reset Routes...
    'verify' => false, // Email Verification Routes...
  ]);
// Login
Route::get('/', function () { 
  return redirect('login');
});
// Dashboard
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
//admin users
Route::resource('/admin/users', 'Admin\UsersController', ['except' => ['show', 'create', 'store']]);
```

**error screenshots:**

Without trailing slash, my application URL:
[image]

Now if I add a trailing slash to the URL, I get this:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I was able to do it with middleware, editing the .htaccess somehow doesn't work locally or it's not working in my application, anyways, check the solution below:

```
if (preg_match('/.+\/$/', $request->getRequestUri()))
 {
    return Redirect::to(rtrim($request->getRequestUri(), '/'), 301);
 }
```

reference
[here](https://www.dwightwatson.com/posts/redirect-trailing-slashes-in-laravel-5)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class RedirectTrailingSlash
{
    /**
     * @param Request $request
     * @param Closure $next
     * @return mixed|void
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        $pathInfo = $request->getPathInfo();
        if ($request->isMethod('get') && Str::endsWith($pathInfo, '/')) {
            $queryString = count($request->all()) ? '?'.http_build_query($request->all()) : '';
            return response('', 301)->header('Location', rtrim($pathInfo, '/') . $queryString);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).